# Object required when using GetElementByName in VBscript

Tags: authentication, vbscript, html

Im using the following code but get object required on my getelementbyname field. Does anyone know what is going on here?
I tried so many variations:

```
WScript.Quit Main
Call Main
Function Main
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "myurlsamle"
WScript.Sleep 8000
With IE
.document.getElementsByName("UsernameTextBox").value = "myusername"
.document.getElementsByName("PasswordTextBox").value = "mypassword"

End With
End Function
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` does not return an element, but a collection. Try with `getElementsByName('...')[0]` to retrieve the first element found (be careful, maybe there is not any matching element)

Comment: @MCND if they are using VBScript they won't be able to access the collection using `[0]` try `.document.getElementsByName("...")(0).value`.

Comment: @Lankymart, AGGG! My fault. I've been coding javascript for the last 12 hours and I didn't think what I was writing. Thank you.

Comment: Aw damn! I didn't see the plural in there. Ofcourse i meant getElementByName. 
If i use element instead it should work then? Ill have to check tomorrow. Thanks a whole lot!

Comment: @BruceBlack there isn't a `getElementByName()` method because the very nature of the `name` attribute means you could have more than one element with the same `name`. If you want a single element returned use `getElementById()` because `id` is unique across elements.

Comment: @Lankymart Makes total sense! Thanks you very much guys